# "The server returned a user enrollment profile" error when enrolling into User Enrollment mode on iOS 13 using OTA

Tags: ios, mdm, ota, configuration-profile, user-enrollment

I've been experimenting with the new User Enrollment MDM mode available in iOS 13 betas. I am adding "AppleManagedID" in the MDM profile, as specified by Apple in the relevant WWDC 2019 session, but when that profile is pushed down as part of a normal over the air flow I can seeing the following error:

> The server returned a user enrollment profile

My interpretation of this is that UE is not supported when doing the OTA flow. But if so, what is the recommended way to deploy UE? I may be able to get it working by manually pushing profiles using Apple Configurator 2, but that doesn't seem fit for production.

I've opened a bug with Apple a few weeks ago but have not received any response. I have verified on the 4th beta (which just came out yesterday), but the same thing happens.

If anyone knows of the right way to deploy UE (without needing the device plugged in), please let me know.

Comment: Were you able to get this solved?

Comment: @Locksleyu Were you able to solve the issue